# How do I find the country where the Latest Value changes the most by year?

Tags: python

Imagine I have data like below.How do I find the country where the Latest Value changes the most by year?

[image]

Comment: Since the definition of variance is the expectation of the squared deviation of a random variable from its population mean or sample mean. Unless you have a population mean or sample mean, you can't compute variance on a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only have 2020 data, so you can only do that year.
If you want a country specific data, you will need more years. Assuming you know that, so I'll continue with variance between countries for 2020.

Gather the data into a list, array, dataframe. If you have a csv file, use pandas as I will do that. I use the statistics package for variance, it also has population variance

```
       import pandas as pd
       from statistics import variance
       df = pd.read_csv("data.csv") # this should be a path if not in wd
       # Add condition to specify year here if years do differ
       # Or add condition to specify country if you have multiple years
       # df = df.loc[df['Country'] == "China"]
       my_var = variance(df["Most Recent Value"])
       print(my_var)
```